# Not connecting to localhost on wamp nor dreamweaver

Tags: wamp, dreamweaver

I got a website folder from a co-worker and am trying to edit it on DreamWeaver CC 2014 on Windows 8.1.

I have installed Wamp, although when I try to go to localhost, it shows that it is not possible to connect to it.

On Dreamweaver, it keeps saying that the testing server is not defined. Even though I set it up as usual and how it used to work.

I don't really understand why. And don't even know where to look. My Apache error log doesn't show anything weird, so give me some suggestions.

Thank you.
(I'm quite sure you will want logs or something, but I'm lost and don't know what will be more useful right now.)

Answer (score 0):

Well. I just made a clean copy, installation and connection and it worked.
Guess that too many attempts made it from bad to worse.